# getting shadow error with tooltips on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am getting an issue with tooltips not clearling properly - they leave a grey shadow until I move the frame window.

This new in my complex app. I cannot make an SCCE as the error then does not occur. However, I have captured a picture.

If anyone could shed light on why this is happening - that would be great

[image]

Comment: This looks like an opacity issues from a bad paint chain.  You may have a component that it's calling `super.paintXxx` ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes super.paintComponent(g); appears in many places. It's from code example I found on web. Is it bad to do this?

Comment: @MadProgrammer was telling you to add the call to `super` because it **should** be there.  It is important. --  Did your *"I cannot make an SCCE"* mean you tried making an SSCCE but the tool-tips were OK in the shorter code?

Comment: Calling `super.paintComponent` is very important, particularly when dealing with transparent (or faked translucent) components.  Also make sure that you are not using transparent colors (colors with an Alpha value less the 255 or 1f)

Comment: @MadProgrammer 2 things. Where do I put super.paintcomponent? in every paintComponenet override?   Secondly, I am DEFINITELY using transparent colors why is that an issue?

Comment: 1- You should call `super.paintComponent` as the first call when ever you override `paintComponent`.  2- Swing doesn't actually have a concept of translucency.  It's either opaque or it's not.  If you try and use a translucent or transparent color on an opaque component, Swing won't paint what's underneath it as, as far as it's concerned, the component is opaque...

Answer (score 1):

> I am DEFINITELY using transparent colors why is that an issue?

See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for the answer to that and a couple of solutions.

Comment: +1 for a valuable article illustrating that "If you do not honor the [_opaque property_](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#props) you will likely see visual artifacts."